# can't view script56.chm (jscript/vbscript help) on windows 7 (it comes up blank)

Tags: vbscript, jscript

I can't view script56.chm (jscript/vbscript help) on windows 7 (it comes up blank)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2764

[image]

[image]

Comment: related- http://superuser.com/questions/323933/how-does-windows-security-warning-do-you-want-to-run-this-file-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow [Install instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2764) from the download link provided:

> In some situations, content will not be visible in the Help window
>   after saving the file to your machine. In this case, you will need to
>   give the file permission to display content.
>
> - Right click on script56.chm
> - Choose Properties
> - Click on "Unblock"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Delete the thing that causes that [trusted zone message](https://superuser.com/questions/323933/how-does-windows-security-warning-do-you-want-to-run-this-file-work).

Then when you run script56.chm it will display

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads>streams script56.chm

Streams v1.56 - Enumerate alternate NTFS data streams
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\Users\user\Downloads\script56.chm:
   :Zone.Identifier:$DATA       26

C:\Users\user\Downloads>streams /?

Streams v1.56 - Enumerate alternate NTFS data streams
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: streams [-s] [-d] <file or directory>
-s     Recurse subdirectories
-d     Delete streams


C:\Users\user\Downloads>streams -d script56.chm

Streams v1.56 - Enumerate alternate NTFS data streams
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\Users\user\Downloads\script56.chm:
   Deleted :Zone.Identifier:$DATA

C:\Users\user\Downloads>script56.chm

C:\Users\user\Downloads>
```

[image]